# How to calculate attrition rate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

The table structure is

userID – unique ID

Billing Month – Month that bill was paid

The data which I have is for 1 year or 12months

**I have to calculate the total number of users who are leaving each month.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `'i'` with `@i`?

Comment: `i` must be between 1 and 11 so that `i+1` wont give you an invalid month 13 for example

Comment: Note that you refer to `subscriberid` when it appears you mean `userid`.

Comment: What version of MSSMS are you using? Because the answer will be so much simpler if you have access to LEAD and LAG which requires `sql-server2012`

Answer (score 1):

If you think about using a `WHILE` loop in SQL Server, you are doing it wrong 90% of the time. Use a set-based approach!

In your case, you can join the table to itself can count how many customers are missing in the following month:

```
SELECT      t1.BillingMonth,
            Attrition = COUNT(*)
FROM        #my_table   t1
LEFT JOIN   #my_table   t2  ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
                            AND t1.BillingMonth = t2.BillingMonth - 1
WHERE       t2.UserID IS NULL
GROUP BY    t1.BillingMonth
```

**How it works:** for each user, `LEFT JOIN` it to the same user in the following month. Then we simply count how many users aren't there next month (`WHERE t2.UserID IS NULL`).

`LEFT JOIN` is used because it will return `NULL` if the user isn't there for the next month. `INNER JOIN` will NOT return the row if the user isn't found in the following month.

Comment: Try removing the condition on `@MaxMonth`

Comment: Your `not in` is replaced by a left join and `is null` test. Otherwise it's the same as yours (and mine). Running multiple months requires a `group by` while you didn't need it when running a single month at a time.

Comment: Think about it like this: `t1.userid` is for this month. `t2.userid` is for next month. If the user isn't there next month, her `t2.userid` is null. That's what you are looking for - a user who has dropped out.

Comment: +1 for the set based solution. Wholeheartedly agree that loops are major code smell for SQL development.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. if t1.BillingMonth = 'Feb' t2.BillingMonth - 1 becomes 'Jan', then t1.userid is for this month. t2.userid is for last month right?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using a `while` loop. Create a temp table and insert values in the loop. Then `select` from temp table after the loop.

```
declare @i int = 1;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp; 
create table #temp(monthid int,usercount int);
while @i < 12
begin
select @i+1, count(userid) 
into #temp
from table 
where BillingMonth = @i 
and userid not in (select userid from table where BillingMonth = @i+1)
set @i = @i + 1
end
select * from #temp
```

Comment: see the modified answer which creates and inserts values into a temp table.

Comment: try the modified version

Comment: Although you could run it piecemeal to delete/create the temp table, you need to run the whole thing at once for the loop and variable declaration. You can run the `select` at the end as many times as you want of course.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use date as the data type for billing month, since it will make calculations easier and you won't end up in issues with different years or if your data spans for example from November to March.

It looks like you're actually only interested about the last month per user, so that can be fetched using row_number, with something like this:

```
select * from
(
  select UserID, BillingMonth, 
  row_number() over (partition by UserID order by BillingMonth desc) as RN
) X
where RN = 1
```

And if you only want the counts, you can of course use just this:

```
select BillingMonth, count(*) from
(
  select UserID, BillingMonth, 
  row_number() over (partition by UserID order by BillingMonth desc) as RN
) X
where RN = 1
group by BillingMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to take the approach you started with and just correlate the subquery. It's essentially identical to your query except that the month plus one logic is handled dynamically:

```
select t.BillingMonth, count(t.userid) 
from <T> t
where t.BillingMonth <> '<MaxMonth>' and t.userid not in (
    select t2.userid from <T> t2
    where t2.BillingMonth = cast(cast(t.BillingMonth as int) % 12 + 1 as varchar(2))
)
group by t.BillingMonth
```

You won't want to try connecting your final month with the previous month (which is actually a year ago.) But I don't know what your data looks like so I just added the "MaxMonth" condition. There's probably a better way to do it though based on current date or the maximum in your data.

I'm treating your `BillingMonth` as a string value as you appear to do in your code above. Also I'm handling the case where you need to roll over from December to January.

The above query will only return 11 rows. The attrition for the final month is logically zero or not available from the data.